# SQL output piped to `kubectl exec` crashes, if not replacing TABS with SPACES

Tags: linux, bash, sed, io-redirection, kubernetes

## The context:

I'm generating SQL from a backup dump, inside a subshell, to then pipe it to mysql for execution:

```
(
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;";
 tar --to-stdout -xvjf archive.tar;
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;";
) | mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -D mydatabase
```

This works fine; I can see the data restored in the tables.

---

Unfortunately `mysqld` is part of a Kubernetes cluster, so I need to forward the SQL output via `kubectl exec`:

```
(
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;";
 tar --to-stdout -xvjf archive.tar;
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;";
) | kubectl exec -i mysql-pod -- mysql -D mydatabase
```

that fails & crashes with:

> x backup-dump.sql
> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 143: MySQL server has gone away
> command terminated with exit code 1
> : Write error
> tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

With some debugging I figured out that tab characters (`\t`) break the `tar` extraction; a fix is to replace all the `\t` with spaces (`\s`) via `sed` regex.

---

## The problem:

the output from `tar` needs to be normalized using `sed`, before directing the subshell *stdout* to `mysql`.

### The question:

*Why does the command fail when piped to Kubernetes? And what's a understandable/non-convoluted way to **intercept the `stdout` and add an intermediate pipe** that works with `kubectl`?*

#### I tried

```
(
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;";
 tar --to-stdout -xvjf archive.tar | sed 's/\t/\s/g';
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;";
) | mysql -D mydatabase
```

<sup>(but the regex replacement isn't performed; `tar` doesn't output to the `pipe`)</sup>

and

```
(
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;";
 tar --to-stdout -xvjf archive.tar;
 echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;";
) \
  | sed 's/\t/\s/g' \
  | mysql -D mydatabase
```

<sup>(but the `tar` command fails before completing the sub-shell execution)</sup>

Comment: `s/\t/\s/g` would replace tab characters by literal `s` characters I think?

Comment: Indeed it would; you would need something like `s/\t/ /g` but that would also collapse any tabs embedded into VARCHAR or TEXT fields into single spaces.  Something more elaborate would be needed (the example in the OP has the same potential issue) to avert this.  However, my tests with `tar xfzO archive.tgz | sed` appear to be working as intended in this case, so I'm somewhat stymied.

Comment: @steeldriver as mentioned in the question, it replaces with the `space` character (note the escaping `slash`).

Comment: @DopeGhoti I updated the question title to clarify. If you re-read the question, the issue isn't with the `sed` itself, but with piping the output via `kubectl exec` (while piping directly to `mysql` doesn't fail).